# Mail Merge in Word Does Not Move to Next Field and Input Value

Tags: mailmerge, word-2013

I'm running a Mail Merge using Word 2013.
I have a list with 3 items on it [Fig. 3], and I have a template that I've written.
The template has some basic formatting and displays the line items (1 on each line) with the calculated Total Shipping (Freight), Total before tax, Total VAT amount and Grand Total in separate lines below that.  To get to the next line item I am using the NEXT record rule.  Each line item shows on its own line, but the Total Shipping, Total before tax and Grand Total do not populate unless I manually update the fields [Fig. 1]. I have played with the NEXTIF rule and I can get those fields to update automatically, but I have 5 lines in the item table and the other lines fill with the first record [Fig. 2].  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  End goal is to have anything from 1 to 5 records/line items in the table and for the bottom fields to populate during the mailmerge.

The NEXTIF rule is populated like so: `{ NEXTIF { MERGEFIELD "Product_Product_ID" } = "True" }`

Thank you kindly

Screenshot of my populated table using NEXT:
[image]

Screenshot of populated table using NEXTIF:
[image]

Screenshot of the data table:
[image]

Comment: Is your NEXTIF definitely testing the right condition, i.e. is the value of { MERGEFIELD "Product_product_ID" } the exact text string "True" ?

Comment: No, I was aiming for an "if it exists" condition. The product ID is a 4 digit number. If my NEXTIF statement tests for "true" as a text string in the product id, could it work if I use { NEXTIF { MERGEFIELD "LastItem" } = 0}? - sorry, I can't test this at the moment. So if the LastItem does not equal 0, it won't move to the next record and therefore exit the loop?

Comment: Is the Product ID a 4 digit number in every record? Or is it 4 digits unless it "doesn't exist"? In the latter case, if the value when it doesn't exist matches "" ((i.e. an empty string) then you may be able to change '= "True"' to '<> ""' Beyond that, I would have to consider the logic - Word's Mailmerge doesn't really "loop", it just moves on/terminates.

Comment: Yes, the product ID is 4 digits in every record. There would not be a blank product ID. The logic is that PART1  would have have 5 lines in a table, but only 3 (or 1, or 2, or 4, or 5) might have valid data and the following lines in the table need to be blank. PART 2 then needs to move on ans calculate the fields in the 2nd table (shipping, tax, etc). NEXT does PART1 but doesn't do PART 2 without a manual update of the remaining fields. NEXTIF does both but populates the trailing fields in table1 - not desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am testing using Windows Word 2010. It is possible that other versions (particularly on Mac) behave differently, so let us know which version you are using.

Previously, I had assumed that you were doing a one-many merge (with data for multiple pages, but a maximum of 5 rows per page). Now I read your text again, I realise you data source probably really does have a maximum of 5 rows, and that you were seeking a way to detect the non-existence of a row. Assuming that is the case, then...

It's important that you are "completing the merge", i.e. outputting to a new document, or whatever. Previewing the merge only gives you an indication of what is going to happen, and can sometimes be misleading.

To test for non-existence, you should be able to test

```
{ IF  { MERGEFIELD Product_ID } = "" }
```

as I indicated in my previous comment. Although there may be times when that does not display the expected result during preview, it should display the expected result when you complete the merge. (It will probably only require a field update to display correctly during preview.

I suspect that the issue related to non-display of totals is related to the way you are calculating them. If you are using a running total and not checking the existence of a value in every row, things will probably go wrong. You are clearly doing it differently from me, as I actually see an error message in my total:

```
!Unexpected end of formula.
```

That's if I do it by having the following at the beginning of the page

```
{ SET Total 0 }
```

and the following calculation in each row

```
{ SET Total { =Total+{ MERGEFIELD Extended_Amount } } }
```

To fix that, I think you would need to do something like

```
{ SET Total { =Total+{ IF { MERGEFIELD Extended_Amount } = "" 0 { MERGEFIELD Extended_Amount } } } }
```

However, another for that calculation you could use a completely different approach - select the table, insert a bookmark, let's say "datatable", then use a field like

```
{ =SUM(datatable [F:F]) }
```

or if you want the field code to be resolved in an output document, use

```
{ QUOTE { =SUM(datatable [F:F]) } }
```

If you *are* doing a one-many merge (more than 5 records in your data source) then the { NEXT } field approach will not work. I can detail what you need to do, but the outline is that you have to have something that tells you when a page's data ends, and use that to suppress the output of rows that should not be there. (An alternative that some might consider to be simpler might be to have a row count in the first row for each page, and have an IF block that inserts the correct number of table rows+contents depending on the row count_.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm using Word 2013 and CRM Dynamics Online on PC.  My merge will only be 1 page (with upto 5 rows). No records on any other pages.

It should be noted that the 'calculated' fields at the end of the merge are fetched from the table in the 3rd screenshot above, i.e. I am only trying to place a field value into these fields and not performing a calculation.  It is these fields that do not update automatically when using 'NEXT', even if I complete the merge.   

The row count suggestion might work though, I'll try that

Comment: As far as the calculated fields are concerned, are the same values available in all the records that will be consumed by the page? If not, they would have to be in the *last record that the page consumes". If you were using NEXT and you only had 3 rows of data, by the time the values are output at least one NEXT would have moved the data source past the last record. Another possibility would be to put them all in the first record, and use SET fields to copy them into local variables before the first NEXT or NEXTIF. (I haven't actually checked all that, but I think it is how it would work).

Comment: Using SET was the ticket!! Thank you.